# Reading incoming HTTP headers with node.js

Tags: javascript, json, variables, http-headers, node.js

Now as example, I'm getting an response which has partially the key/values as an javascript object:

```
status: '200 OK',
'content-encoding': 'gzip'
```

I can easily read out and log the status message by: headers.status but when I try to log the content-encoding (which I need in this particular situation) it errors on:

```
headers.'content-encoding' <- obviously the quotes it doesn't like
headers.content-encoding <- obviously the '-' it doesn't like
```

How am I suppose to get/read/log it's content-encoding value?

Greets,

m0rph3v5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Javascript also supports square bracket notation for referring to properties so if `headers` is an appropriate object, you can use `headers['content-encoding']`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, stupidly enough all I tried that way was headers.['content-encoding'] not thinking I'd be combining the two by accident. :)

Comment: There is always a first time :-) Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript properties have names as you know. When the name is a legal identifier and you know the literal name you want when you're writing the code, you can use it with dotted notation.

```
var foo = headers.foo;
```

When the name isn't a legal identifier, or if you want to determine the name you're looking up at runtime, you can use a string:

```
var encoding = headers['content-encoding'];
```

or

```
var name = 'content-encoding';
var encoding = headers[name];
```

or even

```
var x = 'encoding';
var encoding = headers['content-' + x];
```

As you can see, it doesn't have to be a *literal* string. This is very handy for general-purpose functions that have to accept a property name as a function argument or similar.

Note that property names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should install the very good [express](http://expressjs.com/) framework. I really simplifies node.js webdevelopment.

You could install it using npm

```
npm install express
```

This snippet shows you how to set headers and read headers

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.header('a'));
    res.header('time', 12345);

    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Curl from command line

```
$curl http://localhost:3000/ -H "a:3434" -v
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> a:3434
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< time: 12345
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 11
< Date: Tue, 28 Dec 2010 13:58:41 GMT
< X-Response-Time: 1ms
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
Hello World
```

The log outputting the header send via curl to node server:

```
$ node mo.js 
3434
```